# xlFormulas2 is empty in professional plus 2016 edition causing subscript out of range exception

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, excel-365

I have 2 environment one with **MS office 365 APPs for enterprise** and other with **professional plus 2016.**
The Macro code works fine in MS office 365 APPs for enterprise edition but facing 'subscript out of range' exception in professional plus 2016 at Selection.Find function.

While debugging noticed that xlFormulas2 is empty which might causing the error, not sure why xlFormulas2 is empty in professional plus 2016 but -4185 in the other environment which works fine.

```
Sub AA_01_Spring_China_Individual()
sNumber = InputBox("Which week you would like to update?", "Week No:")
sResponse = "Week " & sNumber

Sheets("BD Calls").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="Beijing", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `LookIn:=xlFormulas` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `xlFormulas2` is for Office 365. To make the find work in both the cases you can avoid the error like ...

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim foundCl As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set foundCl = Selection.Find(What:="Beijing", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)
If foundCl Is Nothing Then
Set foundCl = Selection.Find(What:="Beijing", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print foundCl.Address
foundCl.Activate
End Sub
```